# Android app versioning set initial version number

Tags: android, versioning

My question is related to versioning, in concrete, initial version of my app.

It's been two years working in my Android app and after a very hard and almost never-ending work I'm ready to release first demo version to market, the fact is I don't know how to set an initial version number. I'll explain better my doubts:

If we talk about all the time / effort / features my app includes up to the moment (I have a version history file where I track changes) I could say my app is in version 4 or 5 but my logic says being the first version going to be released on market I should set version to 1.0

With this, I don't know whether to keep my current version that is 5.something or to re-adjust all my big version history file so the last modification matches 1.0 (quite complex though) or just simply leave version history as it is and set initial version to 1.0 at the current development leaving all previous 2 years developments unversioned.

Edit 1:

My current version number is already in the form of 5.0.20170619 like @Darish suggests but my doubts on what to do come because I personally agree with @Joshua and @Darish that first release version should has 1.0 (it's like common sense) but on the contrary 1.0 doesn't reflect the real effort and work this app has at this stage and besides if I'd anyway like to go with 1.0 and had to adjust all lines in "Version History" so current development matches 1.0 could be a like a nightmare if I'm expecting to make it real (I wouldn't like to set random numbers).

Edit 2:

In the end and after thinking for a long time I decided that it's best to start by 1.0. At the same time I have to say that "refactoring" my current "Version History" file will be a pain in the ass but my conclusion is it's best to do it.

Comment: I think you should stay with '5.something'. When user will commit some errors, it will be much easier for you to track from which version of your app the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such strict rules, anyway here given some common practices.

- First beta version going to be released on market should set a
  version number less than 1.0
- First stable version going to be released on market should set
  version to 1.0

**Here are some possible versioning schemes:**

- major/minor/build number, such as 3.1.52041 . The build number can
  just be an internal increment in the build system
- major/minor /build date stamp, such as 3.1.20121204

**side note:-** Anyway if you really want to continue the current versioning scheme, you can give it a version name like *5.0.20170619*

Answer (score 1):

Since it's been released for the first time you should set it to 1.0. Cause your users don't know any about the other

Comment: You are right @Joshua, my users don't know about other versions, in fact I still don't have users but you could know about an app and download it for the first time when it's in an advanced stage, for example version 3.xx, so for me this is not an issue. Please, check my edit when you have time.

Answer (score 1):

If it were a hardware product, I'd say you give it a version name. You could still give it any version number based on the stage of your product. But it's best if you start with 1.0 so that your users can keep track of your product accurately at any stage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and time @Joshua! I appreciate it and I'll start with 1.0. Now I'm convinced :)

Comment: No problem, Always here